# Nifi: how to transfer only last file from the flowFile list?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to get all  flowfile from the  queu   which  fileSize  is greater  than 831  and then put  them  into  the  list  after that   catch  last flowfile from the  list  and  transfer to  success relationship  and finally  remove all other  flowfiles  ,  here is  my  code   which throws  exception that **transfer relationship not specified** , what  should  i  change  in this case?

```
 import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get()
def  n=0;
if(!flowFile)return
def size = flowFile.getAttribute('fileSize');
log.error(size.toString())
int value = size as Integer;

if((value/831)>1){
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {

        if( size == ff.getAttribute('fileSize') ) n++; return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
        return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE
    }

})
session.transfer(ffList.get(n-1),REL_SUCCESS)
//session.remove(ffList);
}
session.remove(flowFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get flow file from queue you have to do something with it.

this code returns you a flowFile list:

```
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){...})
```

if you wand just remove all of them except the last one just put this code after transferring the last one:

```
session.remove( ffList[0..-2] )
```

---

and i guess there is a mistake in this line:

```
if( size == ff.getAttribute('fileSize') ) n++; return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
```

the command `return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE` executed in any case because it's not under `if`.

i think should be like this:

```
if( size == ff.getAttribute('fileSize') ){
    n++; 
    return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE
}
```

Comment: Thank   you  it  was  very  helpful